# Plotly links in labels disappear when you hover off the point

Tags: python, plotly

This is a bit of a stupid problem but I'm using plotly for a 3d Scatter plot, essentially tweaking [the Les Miserables plot in the docs](https://plot.ly/python/3d-network-graph/), and I've managed to put links to the Wikipedia page for each node in the node labels.

Essentially, I'm replacing this line (in block 6 on that tutorials page): `labels.append(node['name'])`

with this line:
`labels.append('<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}">{}</a>'.format(node['name'], node['name']))`

Works like a charm! Except that when I hover over the node, the label appears, but then when I go to click the link in the label, the label disappears (because I have oh-so-slightly hovered *off* of the node).

Like I said, kind of a stupid problem, but I really like the linking in the labels and this makes them almost unusable. Any ideas for how to deal with this (is there a way to set a lag for how quickly the labels disappear when you hover off? can the labels themselves trigger the hover?) would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a first draft example of what I'm working on:
https://plot.ly/~seth127/6

Thanks!

Comment: Quite tricky using only Plotly in Python. You could use `Dash` and add the information to a text field which does not disappear or you save it as a HTML file and modify the `plotly_hover` event.

Comment: hmm, thanks. This is making me think maybe I need to make the jump to d3.js or something. Plotly is powerful, but certainly has some limitations once you get in too deep.